# Why Sublime Text occasionally creates a new file itself with only one comma in it?

Tags: sublimetext4

I am writing paper with LaTeX tools in Sublime Text 4 in Windows 11 platform. Occasionally, a strange phenomenon occurs where a new file page shows up in Sublime Text itself with only one comma in it. As is shown in the following image. I don't know why it happens and what's wrong with my Sublime Text. Anyone also suffers this and helps me out? Thanks!

I have attempted to check the user's settings of LaTeX Tools, and got nothing until now.

[image]

Comment: It's notable that this problem shows up even when I am doing nothing with Sublime Text.

Comment: You forgot the image. Also you might want to include OS and sublime text version. Also maybe plugins/features enabled.

Comment: @matt It's weird, I remember posting a shortcut previously. I will post it right now. Thank you.